# Why can we take the log of both sides?

Tags: logarithms

I was watching a video that proves the "Log of a power" rule.

1. I'm just having trouble understanding the loga(a^x) = x  rule - which he uses in the proof
2. And I don't get why you can log both sides. I know whatever you do to one side of a equation you can do to the other - but I still think there's more to it than just that shallow understanding. As soon as I log something I am saying its a exponent - I am basically going from working with exponentiations to working with exponents - what are the steps behind this?
3. Also if 10^x = 10^2 - the bases would be the same - so intuitively I would say that the only differences can possibly be in the exponents - so x = 2. But what is the actual way to prove this? Can you show me all the steps that get us to x = 2

[image]

Comment: Why you can log both sides? Because if $a=b$ then $f(a)=f(b)$ by the definition of a function, here $f:x\mapsto\log x$, given $a,b\in\operatorname{dom}f$.

Comment: For $1$: intuitively, $\log_a(a^x)$ is what we're asking for in the question: to what power do I have to raise $a$ to get $a^x$, which is $x$, and therefore $\log_a(a^x)=x$.

Comment: Rainier thanks - I understand am smacking myself on the head now

Answer (score 1):

Here use that the function $f(x)=\log_a(x)$ is well defined, that is $a=b \Rightarrow f(a) = f(b)$. Then $$a^{mn} = x^n \Rightarrow \log_a(a^{nm})= \log_a(x^n)$$

And the facts $\log_aa^{mn} = mn\log_aa$, $\log_a a = 1$ and $\log_ax^n = n\log_a x$.

Answer (score 0):

As [Hakim points out in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990819/why-can-we-take-the-log-of-both-sides#comment2027773_990819), doing an operation to both sides of an equation is logically valid because logs are well-defined functions.

If you still don't like the given proof, then here's an equivalent proof that does everything in a single chain of equalities but uses substitutions instead:
\begin{align*}
\log_a(x^n)
&= \log_a((a^{\log_a x})^n) &\text{by substituting } x = a^{\log_a x}\\
&= \log_a(a^{n\log_a x}) &\text{since in general $(b^c)^d = b^{cd} = b^{dc}$}\\
&= n\log_a x &\text{since in general} \log_m (m^y) = y  
\end{align*}